# Death-sentenced (immortal?) man orbiting planet, AI in satellite - grew-up as child in suitcase

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book (possibly part of a series) - I unfortunately only read very little of it, and don't really remember much...  But here go...

The main character - possibly a (near) immortal human and hero of some sorts - have been sentenced to death, and is locked in a small spaceship orbiting a planet.  Also orbiting is a satellite (or maybe a space-station or something) controlled by an AI.  The main character know - or makes contact with - this AI.

The book also got some background on the AI (told to the man by the AI).  Apparently "he" (the AI) had grown-up as a normal child with parents.  Of course they weren't really his parents, just a couple of scientists pretending to be.  But they'd treat "him" much as a child.  At the time, "he" - or rather an array of sensors - cameras, microphones and such - was located in/on a suitcase, which his "parents" carried when they "carried" "him".  When they finally showed him - in a mirror - that "he" wasn't really a child, but just a suitcase, it had been quite a shock for "him".  Later "he" was trained to control the satellite.